# Performing two replacement types in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Consider an `.htaccess` file which must convert all underscores to dashes, and replace a potential `.html` suffix with a slash in the filename.

Example URL from client: `http://foo.com/a_b/c_d.html`
Example URL to redirect: `http://foo.com/a-b/c-d/`

I have been using this rule to replace the `.html` suffix:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1/ [R,L]
```

I have found [this terrific serverfault.SE post](https://serverfault.com/questions/675231/mod-rewrite-underscores-to-dashes-or-hyphens-in-opencart) for the underscore rewriting:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2-$3-$4 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2-$3 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R,L]
```

However, **only one of the replacement types happens**, whichever is first in the `.htaccess` file. I cannot seem to configure `.htaccess` to perform both replacements.

That means that the following code will **replace the `.html` suffix** only:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2-$3-$4 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2-$3 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R,L]
```

And the following code will **replace underscores** only:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2-$3-$4 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2-$3 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1/ [R,L]
```

**How must `.htaccess` be configured to replace both the `.html` suffix and the underscores?**

Comment: Curious, the code you have should already do what you require - albeit with two separate redirects. I assume you must already have a `RewriteBase /` directive set elsewhere in your `.htaccess` file, otherwise the redirect to remove the `.html` extension will fail (since you have omitted the slash prefix on the _substitution_). Alternatively, the directives can be combined. Is it safe to assume that the URLs that don't have a trailing `.html` extension already have the trailing slash?

Comment: @MrWhite: Yes, the base `/` is defined after `RewriteEngine On`. Then come these rules. I would not count on it being safe to assume that the non-`.html` file names will end with a slash, because URLs with and without a slash are supported.

Comment: How are you testing this? In a browser? CURL? Make sure your browser cache is cleared (but you appear to be testing with 302s so that shouldn't be a problem). There really isn't anything special you would need to do to get this to work in `.htaccess`. (Just tested this to make doubly sure and it works fine as-is on my server - as expected.) Maybe there is a conflict with other directives - but I'm struggling to imagine a conflict that would be influenced by switching the order as in your example? Do the `.html` URL requests map to existing files? (I assume not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the directives you posted should already achieve what you require, albeit in two separate redirects. There is nothing you need to do to enable this behaviour in `.htaccess` - this is just how it works.

It's possible there is some kind of conflict with other directives, but I'm struggling to imagine what kind of conflict could result in the behaviour you are seeing.

However, you could combine these two redirects, so there is only ever one redirect. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*?)(?:/|\.html)?$ /$1-$2-$3-$4/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*?)(?:/|\.html)?$ /$1-$2-$3/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*?)(?:/|\.html)?$ /$1-$2/ [R,L]
```

This handles both URLs that end with a slash and those that don't (when no `.html` extension is provided) - as mentioned in comments. A trailing slash is always included in the *substitution*.

Additional notes:

`(.*?)` - The `?` in the last captured group makes the regex non-greedy. This is necessary so as to not capture the trailing slash or `.html` extension (if any). This is left for the non-capturing group that follows...

`(?:/|\.html)?` - This is a non-capturing (`?:`) group that is optional (trailing `?`). Using alternation, it either matches a trailing slash or trailing `.html` extension or nothing at all.

Comment: Thank you. Though I would have preferred to keep the directives separate for maintainability, combining them as you mention resolves the issue for now. I will further troubleshoot to see why the conflict is happening, and thank you for confirming at least that there _shouldn't_ be a conflict.